# Setting the current dated sheet as active sheet

Tags: vba

I want to set a the working sheet to current date and along with another word. Everyday i will work on this sheet and the date will change accordingly. How do i define this sheet as active working sheet, since the name will not be constant.

Comment: use the same formula to reference it by name

Comment: `Sheets(Format(Date, "yyMMMdd") & " Test").Activate`

Comment: Or `ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "yyMMMdd") & " Test"` it's not really clear what you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sheet code name vs the actual sheet name!
[image]